# ASIHTTPRequest login method and reuse creds

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to login to my app and have created a bool method to login and thats working great:

```
-(BOOL)User:(NSString *)user password:(NSString *)password
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUseSessionPersistence:YES];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:NO];
    [request setUsername:user];
    [request setPassword:password];
    [request setDomain:domain];
    [request startSynchronous];

    NSError *loginError = [request error];
    if(loginError == nil){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

but now I am trying to use these creds outside this method. I read the documentation and it appears I can use these creds via:

```
//Should reuse our username and password
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

but that would throw an error because request would not be defined. How would I do this?

Comment: `ASIHTTP` has been drepecated and not longer supported since 2012. The leader on this job is from 3-4 years `AFNetworking`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effective range of the `request` variable only in the method. You should also define new variable in the outside of the method.

Like below:

```
//Should reuse our username and password
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation says](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use):

> If `useSessionPersistence` is turned on (it is by default), ASIHTTPRequest stores credentials in memory and can re-use them for subsequent requests.

This means that your credentials will be stored in `sessionCredentialsStore` (and `sessionProxyCredentialsStore` if you're using a proxy). Unless you overwrite them, they will be automatically applied to all subsequent requests. Both of these variables are `static` global variables.

So, just make a request as normal, and the credentials will be applied to the next request as long as you don't modify the credentials store.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about what you are asking but as far as I understand your concern is about extracting user credentials after the request has been fired. Is that correct?

I think the ideal way to do this is to never let go of the request in the first place (OR simply cache using `Keychain`). So basically hold this `request` variable as an instance variable(ivar) of a particular object (potentially a singleton manager type class that handles login tasks). Example

```
// LoginManager.h

@import Foundation;

@interface LoginManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) ASIHTTPRequest *request;

@end
```

---

```
// LoginManager.m


#import "LoginManager.h"

@interface LoginManager ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) ASIHTTPRequest *request;

@end

@implementation LoginManager

+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    static LoginManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(BOOL)User:(NSString *)user password:(NSString *)password
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    self.request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.request setUseSessionPersistence:YES];
    [self.request setUseKeychainPersistence:NO];
    [self.request setUsername:user];
    [self.request setPassword:password];
    [self.request setDomain:domain];
    [self.request startSynchronous];

    NSError *loginError = [request error];
    if(loginError == nil)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

@end
```

Access it via:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[LoginManager sharedManager] request]

NSLog(@"%@", request.username);
NSLog(@"%@", request.password);
```